# NVidia Surround 2D on Multiple Monitors at Different Resolutions (black bars desired) with GTX 1080

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have never used NVidia Surround (2D) and am considering a monitor upgrade; I want to be sure it will work before I buy.  I have an NVidia GTX 1080 Ti and want to play some games I already know are compatible with wide resolutions, like Forza.  I want to buy a 40" 4k monitor for the center and then on the sides pivot two 1080p monitors to portrait mode.

I want/expect black bars on the top and bottom (or just top only/bottom only) of the center monitor running at a slightly reduced visible resolution of 3840x1920, and both side monitors will run 1080x1920.  That's a combined res of 6000x1920.  All connections will be HDMI or DP.

Will NVidia Surround support this as I've described?

(Side note: AMD described how they [added support for EyeFinity configs like this years ago](https://community.amd.com/community/gaming/blog/2015/05/12/mixed-resolution-eyefinity), but I can't find any ***recent*** reference to whether NVidia supports this.)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to contact NVidia Support to answer the question.  In short, their answer was **no, all monitors must be running the same resolution for a supported NVidia Surround 2D configuration**.

Here's their exact response:

> From the email description, I understand that you would like to know if you can use 2D surround with three monitors out of which two will run on 1920x1080 resolution.
>
> Please be assured that I will do my best to help you further or point you in the right direction.
>
> We would like to inform you that in surround mode, the resolution will be always same across all displays and the lowest resolution is selected from all monitors connected. That means all three monitors will run on 1920x 1080 resolution.